# how to set foreign key in JPA + REST

Tags: java, jpa

I have following JPA entity

```
my JPA entity :: BookForUser 
@Id
private int id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="e_mail")
private User user;// I do not want User object in the table, 
//I want a string e_mail to be foreign key in my entity table
```

`var booking = {
    e_mail: localStorage.getItem("email"),...`

Above is my JSON code to fill in bookForUser object from JS. I am using JAVA + REST for back end. but after routing the REST call successfully
I am getting an exception

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [com.RRS.config.RRSConfig] in context with path [/RRS_2] threw exception org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "e_mail" at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream@178546ce; line: 1, column: 12] (through reference chain: com.RRS.bean.Reservation["e_mail"])] with root cause com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "e_mail" (class clasName), not marked as ignorable at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream@178546ce; line: 1, column: 12] at  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:51) at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:839)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:1045)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1352)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownVanilla(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1330)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:264)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:125)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bind(ObjectReader.java:1470)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:912)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase.readFrom(ProviderBase.java:811)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.invokeReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:155)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:74)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:155)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1085)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:874)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest.readEntity(ContainerRequest.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.EntityParamValueFactoryProvider$EntityValueFactory.provide(EntityParamValueFactoryProvider.java:96)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParamValueFactoryWithSource.provide(ParamValueFactoryWithSource.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$AbstractMethodParamInvoker.getParamValues(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:127)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:471)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:425)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:383)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:336)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:223)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

e_mail is primary key  for entity User. The table name is same as class name user
As String email is not a good way to keep primary key, I am planning to change it to int userId. But still the problem will remain same for me.

what I want is

```
class User : primary key=email, some other params
class BookForUser : primary key = id, some other params, foreign key = email
```

What I have understood is BookForUser is not have a complete object of User in it. I don't want it.

Is this way of declaring foreign key correct? (I want 1 user = many reservations)

How shall I pass this e mail attribute to my Java code?

Comment: Email ID may not efficient to keep foreign key reference. Elobrate your question well.

Comment: Where is the User class? What is "following JPA entity" class name? Is email not the Id of User? Where is the exception+STACKTRACE? As said above, elaborate your question since what you post is unintelligible

Comment: I guess you are getting a JSON to Java mapping error. If booking is the entity you have mentioned in the post, your json should be like `booking = {
    user:{ e_mail: localStorage.getItem("email"),...} , ...
 }`

Comment: I am getting proper output for e_mail: localStorage.getItem("email")

Comment: So, you have a field of type String, named `e_mail`, in the JSON. And you're trying to unmarshal this JSON to which Java class? If that class is `BookForUser`, why do you expect this to work? Is there any property of type String named `e_mail` in that class? No, there is not. Create a class that matches with what you send, as JSON, from the browser. Then, using Java code, with the help of the JPA API, transform the instance of that class to a BookForUser. And respect the Java/JavaScript conventions: no underscore in fields.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, having a string such as an email address as your primary is not a good idea. What you can have is:

Make the primary key of the user an integer and have a field for email which would be unique. This is allow you to have integer primary keys (simpler to use and reference to) and avoid duplicates of email addresses.

Another way could be having a class for **User** and a class simply for **Books**.
These would be different at the moment with no links between them. You would then have a third class that would connect them using their Primary Key in **UserReservedBooks**

Example: `Class UserReservedBooks` { `idReservation` (your primary key for this class), `idUser` -> the primary key for user, `idBook` -> the primary key for the book, ... other parameters specific to the reservation such as date it was reserved, etc.)

The advantage to this approach is:

1. 1 User can have multiple reservation
2. It will allow you (if you wish) to see which users reserved a specific book
3. You can also have a user reserve multiple books at once.
4. The one book can be reserved by multiple people.
5. Your user's will have unique email addresses
6. You can avoid the duplication of books.